# How do you add a mouseListener to the label of a jTabbedPane tab?

Tags: java, swing

I added a JLabel as a component of a tab in a JTabbedPanel and added a mouseListener to the label, which works fine (I'm adding a popup menu to the tab's "tag"). The problem is that the JLabel encompasses just the text, and not the space on either side. Is there a way to capture the whole area on and around the label so that a listener can be added?

This is the general idea:

```
tabbed.addTab("Title",jPanel1);
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Title");
label1.addMouseListener( ... code to show a popup menu ...);
tabbed.setTabComponentAt(0,label1);
```

As I said, this all works: I can switch tabs and show the popup menu when I right-click the label; the only problem is that if I click to the right or left of the label text, the mouseListener is not triggered, presumably because the JLabel's boundaries are those of the text only.

Comment: How would you switch tabs then?

Comment: Show more detail and also code of what have you tried so far.

Comment: When right-clicking the selected tab, I show a pop-up menu; otherwise, I switch tabs.

Comment: Maybe in a custom `TabbedPaneUI`?

Comment: @trashgod Do you have any hints for proceeding with your suggested approach? Thanks.

Comment: No; I'd use the approach illustrated in the [`TabComponentsDemo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg).